# Elegir aleatoriamene pareja de valores, cada uno en tuplas diferentes y asociados por índice

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Tengo dos tuplas con valores dentro, lo que quiero hacer es relacionar los valores de ambas, por ejemplo al valor auto le corresponda el valor 40 de la segunda tupla (mismo índice) y obtener una de las parejas de forma aleatoria.

Se que usando diccionarios seria fácil pero tengo restricciones en su uso. ¿Así como están tiene alguna solución? . También, intente con `if` buscando sus indices pero no logro hacer que funcione.

```
import random

cars_type = ("moto", "auto", "camion")
cars_type = random.sample(list(cars_type), 1)
cars_price = (20, 40, 80)
cars_price = random.sample(list(cars_price),1)

print(cars_type, cars_price)
```

Comment: ¿La idea es asociar cada item de la primera tupla con otro de la segunda **aleatoriamente**? ¿Que salida buscas? Algo como `(("moto", 80),  ("auto", 40), ("camion",  20))`

Comment: Exactamente, eso es lo que busco

Comment: En realidad lo que busco es que moto valga 20, auto 40, camion 80 pero tiene que generarse aleaoriamente,  tengo restricciones en el uso de diccionarios

Comment: Es decir, moto vale siempre 20, auto 40 y camión 80. ¿Lo que quieres es retornar una pareja de las tres aleatoriamente o obtener las tres a la vez pero en un orden aleatorio?

Comment: retornar una pareja a la vez pero aleatoriamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `random.choice` o `random.sample` como haces sobre cada tupla obtienes un item aleatorio de cada una de ellas pero lógicamente, excepto azar, no van a coincidir la pareja correcta `car: price`.

Si solo quieres retornar una pareja de forma aleatoria, lo más simple es que elijas aleatoriamente un índice válido de las tuplas (asumo que ambas tiene siempre la misma longitud) y luego lo uses para indizar sobre ambas:

```
import random

cars_type = ("moto", "auto", "camion")
cars_price = (20, 40, 80)

idx = random.randint(0, len(cars_type) - 1)
random_car = (cars_type[idx], cars_price[idx])
print(random_car) # ('auto', 40)
```

O si quieres obtener la pareja en variables separadas simplemente:

```
idx = random.randint(0, len(cars_type) - 1)
car_type, car_price = cars_type[idx], cars_price[idx]
```

Es importante tener en cuenta que `random.randint` a diferencia de `range` si incluye el límite superior, por lo que es necesario restar 1 a la salida de `len`. En caso contrario, en el ejemplo podríamos obtener 3 como índice, el cual es inválido.

Aunque, como comentas, lo más simple sería asociar cada vehículo con su precio usando un diccionario (o una lista de objetos `Car`). De no poder hacer esto, lo que si podrías es usar una tupla de tuplas. La puedes construir con un `for` o directamente con `zip`:

```
cars_type = ("moto", "auto", "camion")
cars_price = (20, 40, 80)
catalogue = tuple(zip(cars_type, cars_price))
print(catalogue) # (('moto', 20), ('auto', 40), ('camion', 80))
```

Con ello facilitas la tarea al no tener que estar asociando los items de cada lista para cualquier operación. Además puedes usar `ramdom.choice` para obtener una pareja de forma aleatoria directamente:

> ```
> >>> random.choice(catalogue)
> ('camion', 80)
> >>> random.sample(catalogue, 2)
> [('camion', 80), ('auto', 40)]
> ```

Comment: Genio, ayer me salvaste y hoy lo volves a hacer , muchas gracias ;)